# How do I create a triangular mesh from a series of Bezier curves that form a closed loop?

Tags: python, mesh, bezier-curves, faces

I am trying to mesh a 3D curve on a 2D plane (important that it's 3D) using Blender's Python interface. All of the parts of the object are Bezier curves. Here are the things I have tried:

- Skin meshing

  - Received a typeerror, although it's been so long that I can't remember exactly what it was.
- Individually clicking through the vertices to try and create a square face

  - No matter what I did, this created triangular elements that were in the entirely wrong places. Some were even outside of the closed curves.
- bpy.data.meshes.new_from_object(obj)

  - If my obj variable was one of my Bezier curves, all Python did was create vertices and connect them on the curve itself. This didn't really solve my issue.

I know that I need to find a way to close the curve, but I'm not sure how to do that/if it's possible for Bezier curves in Python/Blender.

I will refrain from posting the whole code for now, as it is a lot. If snippets of the code would be helpful to answer this question, I am happy to provide them. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean make a mesh from a _projection_ of a 3D curve on to a 2D plane?